# Can I use a splitter for a triple monitor setup?

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I was wondering how I can link 3 monitors to my graphics card.
I want to use the computers as 3 separate monitors (not duplicates).
What splitter should I use? Would a splitter even work?
Note: I am using Win10
Thanks

Here are the parts:
https://pcpartpicker.com/part/aoc-monitor-i2379vhe
https://pcpartpicker.com/part/asus-video-card-strixgtx970dc2oc4gd5

Comment: A splitter would result three monitors displaying the identical thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A splitter would not be necessary as your video card (STRIX-GTX970-DC2OC-4GD5) supports three monitors natively.  They can be connected to up to three of the following ports:
DVI, DVI-I (DVI-D), HDMI 2.0, Display Port.  As your monitor supports HDMI and VGA, you can connect DVI, DVI and HDMI with simple adapters or adapter cables to the HDMI ports for a digital connection.  You could also use a DP to HDMI adapter, but those are usually more costly.

This (or any other) DVI male to HDMI female adapter here will let you use HDMI cables for all three monitors.
[http://www.amazon.com/Importer520-Plated-Female-DVI-D-Adapter/dp/B0035B4LJM](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0035B4LJM)